# cakephp 2 database connection error

Tags: php, mysql, linux, cakephp

I have a db on a Linux machine and my project is on Windows

I want to connect to the local linux db but I'm still getting this error `Database connection "Mysql" is missing, or could not be created.`

my database.php

```
public $default = array(
    'datasource' => 'Database/Mysql',
    'persistent' => false,
    'host' => 'xx.xx.xx.xx',
    'login' => 'xxxxx',
    'password' => 'xxxxx',
    'database' => 'xxxxx',
    'prefix' => '',
    'encoding' => 'utf8',
);
```

I've tried adding `'unix_socket' => '/tmp/mysql.sock'`, same error message.

How can I connect to my remote DB?

Comment: have you created database?

Comment: yes, it was the first thing that I've done.

Comment: What you put in host ? are you working with external mysql server ?

Comment: @Arman Petrosyan yes

Comment: on this case check your external mysql server configs , maybe you haven't access to connect to it.